# Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Product[]'. What is the problem here. React + Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

App.tsx

```
export default function FilterableProductTable() {
  const products: Product[] = [
    { category: "Fruits", price: "$1", stocked: true, name: "Apple" },
    { category: "Fruits", price: "$1", stocked: true, name: "Dragonfruit" },
    { category: "Fruits", price: "$2", stocked: false, name: "Passionfruit" },
    { category: "Vegetables", price: "$2", stocked: true, name: "Spinach" },
    { category: "Vegetables", price: "$4", stocked: false, name: "Pumpkin" },
    { category: "Vegetables", price: "$1", stocked: true, name: "Peas" },
  ];
  return (
    <>
      <Testing data={products} />
    </>
  );
}

interface Product {
  category: string;
  price: string;
  stocked: boolean;
  name: string;
}


function Testing(data: Product[]) {
  return <p>{data[0].category}</p>;
}
```

The error arises from the "Testing" function call declaration. I don't know what is the problem. I tried searching it up, but couldn't figure it out. Iam a beginner.

I tried running the code from a typescript playground and it is working perfectly. But this is a React + Typescript environment and it shows me error.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript expects that the prop `data` to be defined, however, you have not defined a prop, instead, you are directly accessing `data` as if it were a prop.

```
function Testing({ data }: { data: Product[] }) {
  return <p>{data[0].category}</p>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you pass **props** to a component. You should do it that way:

```
export default function FilterableProductTable() {
  const products: Product[] = [
    { category: "Fruits", price: "$1", stocked: true, name: "Apple" },
    { category: "Fruits", price: "$1", stocked: true, name: "Dragonfruit" },
    { category: "Fruits", price: "$2", stocked: false, name: "Passionfruit" },
    { category: "Vegetables", price: "$2", stocked: true, name: "Spinach" },
    { category: "Vegetables", price: "$4", stocked: false, name: "Pumpkin" },
    { category: "Vegetables", price: "$1", stocked: true, name: "Peas" },
  ];
  return (
    <>
      <Testing data={products} />
    </>
  );
}

interface Product {
  category: string;
  price: string;
  stocked: boolean;
  name: string;
}

interface Props {
  data: Product[];
}


function Testing(props: React.PropsWithChildren<Props>) {
  return <p>{props.data[0].category}</p>;
}
```

In general, when you pass data through custom attributes to your component, the data stored by its key name in the component function parameter, which we call **props** as a convention. Then you can access the value by access the attribute name.